# What are the permission needed in VSTS to create Agent pool?

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to setup Build and Release process in on-premises VSTS. I am getting permission error in Agent Pool Creation steps. I was already assigned Administartor role by our TFS Admin Team still I am getting below error.

[image: Agent Pool Creation Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need the collection level `Manage build resources` permission. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops

Probably the easiest way to do this is for your TFS Admin Team to add you to the `Project Collection Build Administrators` security group.

The group is found under *Organization settings* > *Security*

[image]

[image]